# show data from two tables (menu & submenu )

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, menu

Here is what i am doing I have two tables one is Menu and other is subMenu

```
Menu table :
- id
- name
- num

submenu table :
- ids
- id
- sname
- url
```

The link is " **id** " .

i do that for menu but i want to show menu & her submenu

```
<?

    $getcat = mysql_query("select * from menu ORDER BY num ");    
    $recordno = mysql_num_rows($getcat);

    if ($recordno > 0) {
        while ($rowc = mysql_fetch_array($getcat)) {      
            echo " 
            <br>
            $rowc[name] ";
        }
    }
?>
```

and result like this

[image]

and please give the code php to show result .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you might want to change:

```
Menu table :
- id
- name
- num

submenu table :
- id
- menu_id
- sname
- url
```

Doing this helps avoid any ambiguity.

and then use a join

```
<?
$db = mysql_connect('YOUR_DB_ADDRESS','YOUR_DB_USER','YOUR_DB_PASS') or die("Database error");
mysql_select_db('YOUR_DB', $db);


$getcat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu m JOIN submenu sm ON m.id = sm.menu_id  ORDER BY num ");

if (!$getcat) {
   die("Error");
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcat)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['sname'];
}
```

One a side note move to MySQLi

Comment: sorry but that don't work  // Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource //

Answer (score 1):

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab7df/3)

```
select * 
from
  menu m inner join submenu sm 
    on m.id = sm.id
order by m.num
;
```

[image]

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab7df/3)

Comment: how i can show results this don't work ////// while ($rowc = mysql_fetch_array($getcat)) {    ... //////

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to join your sub-menu items first

```
SELECT * FROM menu INNER JOIN submenu ON submenu.id=menu.id ORDER BY num
```

Comment: the submenu table is poorly designed and your code accommodates it